# find function in c++ for a vector

Tags: c++, vector

Okay, so I am new to this, and I am having trouble understanding this.

I made this code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
    vector <int> a;
    int i;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(4);
    a.push_back(5);

    vector <int>::iterator position = find(a.begin(),a.end(),6);
    cout<<*position<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I read everywhere that the `find` function if it doesnt find anything returns the iterator to the end of the vector. So, when, I do this, and search the value `6` which is not present in the vector, it should return the iterator to the end of the vector which is actually `5`. On printing the actual value, it should then print `5` but it prints `0`. Why is it that if it returns the iterator to the last value if `find` doesnt find anything in the vector relating to the value, then it prints `0`?

Comment: It returns what you pass in as the end, which is `a.end()`. Dereferencing `a.end()` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: "t should return the iterator to the end of the vector which is actually 5" - no it isn't, you need to **read the documentation** of `std::vector::end()`. Also, do you think it would make sense to return an iterator to the last element? How would it then be possible to differentiate "not found" from "found at last position"?

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt able to distinguish. My bad. As I said, I am new to this. I wasnt able to understand properly.

Answer (score 4):

No, it will not return *the end of the vector* it will return `vector.end()`

The former implies the last element of the vector, which would be 5.

The latter, `vector.end()`, is [past the end of the vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/)

This adds slight confusion because [`vector.begin()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) does indeed point to the first element of the vector, but this is necessary due to the way you can iterate these containers.

Comment: Oh! I got it now. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @user3776323 be sure to accept the answer if it's the answer you needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it that if it returns the iterator to the last value if find doesnt find anything in the vector relating to the value, then it prints 0

0 is a garbage value that you get when you dereference the end iterator of the vector. This is undefined behavior, so you could potentially get any number at all. A proper code looks like this:

```
vector <int>::iterator position = find(a.begin(),a.end(),6);
if (position != a.end()) {
    cout<<*position<<"\n";
} else {
    cout << "not found" << endl;
}
```

Once you get the result, you need to compare it to `a.end()` to see if the result is valid. If the result is not valid, you may not dereference the iterator to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the documentation for `vector::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end), the `end()` iterator is not the same as the last element in the vector. Rather, it is past the last element. Accessing that element results in undefined behavior.